# Combine php variable and SELECT variables into one SQL Insert query

Tags: php, sql

I've the following query:

```
INSERT INTO 
                                table
                            (
                                memberid,
                                field1,
                                field2,
                                field3
                            )  
                            VALUES
                            (
                                :memberid,              
                                (
                                    SELECT
                                        field1,
                                        field2,
                                        field3
                                    FROM 
                                        table
                                    WHERE 
                                        id = :id
                                )
                            )
```

I'm using PDO prepared statements, but the query doesn't work in this way.

Does anyone know how to combine prepared statements and SELECT variables into one query?

Tnx

Comment: What SQL implementation do you use?

Comment: I'm sorry Victor. I didn't know this feature is available. I will remember that in the future!

Comment: Please don’t answer on your own question if you don’t have an answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered insert-select?

```
INSERT INTO mytable (a,b) 
SELECT :a, b
FROM myothertable
```

Comment: I've tried that, but that isn't working. I get this error:
Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 in

Comment: You're probably using code like "INSERT INTO (a,b,c) SELECT a,b". Post the actual query and we'll count the columns and values for you.

Comment: Thank you. I made a mistake with setting the VALUES parameter (thanks Gumbo)